# can't update data dynamically using ng-charts

Tags: angularjs, charts

I'm trying to make a pie-Chart therefore I'm trying to use ng-charts , it works when the data is static :

```
$scope.graph = {
            height : 500,
            width : 1000
        };

$scope.pieChartData = {
            labels : ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'],
            datasets : [
               {
                    y : [50,10,40]
                }
            ]
       };
```

However when I try to modify labels and datasets with dynamic values , an error accurs saying :

```
Error: b.datasets[0].y is undefined
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ? 
Thank you

Comment: can you provide a plunker ?

Comment: here is the fiddle but it wouldn't work because the data is extracted from API :
http://jsfiddle.net/Lq3pnyg9/3/

Comment: I don't have the answer for your question, but if you are using Chart.js, I would suggest you to take a look at https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js
It's the most up-to-date angular directive for Chart.js

Comment: thank you , you were right , it worked perfectly fine with Chart.js as you recommended